# No puedo agregar un controlador en proyecto MVC ASP.NEt con entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, controller

Cuando quiero agregar el controlador me sale el siguiente error, si podrian ayudarme a resolverlo porfavor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Te **recomiendo** que los errores y el codigo que pongas no sea en formato imagen si no en texto. Un saludo :)

Comment: puedes añadir los pasos que sigues hasta alcanzar ese error para poder reproducirlo?

Comment: @NicolasOñate si los pasos que hago son crear un proyecto asp.net mvc con entity framework, luego paso a crear mi clases en la carpeta models , ya que estoy practicando ORM. Una vez hecha todas las clases y haber puesto mi cadena de conexión en web.config paso a crear mis controladores, pero al momento de pasar a crear el controlador y hago click en aceptar me sale el error que esta en la imagen